# Swipe in openlayers with group layers

Tags: controls, openlayers, swipe, layer

I'm using the example https://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/control/map.control.swipe.html to create my swipe and it worked. However, I want to use a group of layers to choose which one to show, as per the code below.

```
var swipe_control = new ol.control.Swipe();

// Group of layers - menu
var overlays = new ol.layer.Group({
    title: 'Maps',
    fold: 'open',
    layers: [
            new ol.layer.Group({
                title: 'Group 1',
                fold: 'open',
                layers: [
                    swipe_control.addLayer(layer1),
                    swipe_control.addLayer(layer2, true)
                ]
            }),
            new ol.layer.Group({
                title: 'Group 2',
                fold: 'open',
                layers: [
                    swipe_control.addLayer(layer3),
                    swipe_control.addLayer(layer4, true)
                ]
            })  
        ]   
});

map.addControl(swipe_control);
```

My question is: how to use swipe in the group, so that, if I check an option, I set the layer on the right and left? Thanks

Comment: @ViglinoJean-Marc Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Swipe only applies to the layer itself not on a layer group.
Layers inside the layer group must be added/removed from the control when you check the option.

Comment: thanks. I got it. I added the layers in the group and then created a function to check if there is already a layer on the left side, if so, I remove it before including with swipe. Same for the right side.